# Web scraping using python for abstract https://ash.confex.com/ash/2019/webprogram/start.html

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract abstract information  like title, date, author, affiliation, background, methods, results, conclusion using keywords Adoptive cell therapy, Allogeneic, Autologous, Artificial T-Cell Receptors, BCMA, TACI, CD123 from all the page.

using selenium I tried to insert the keyword and open the page but not able to proceed further.

```
import webbrowser
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import wget
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get('https://ash.confex.com/ash/2018/webprogram/meeting.html#Friday')
src = driver.page_source  # gets the html source of the page
parser = BeautifulSoup(src)
mn=[]
list_of_attributes = {"class": "itemtitle"}  # A list of attributes that you want to check in a tag
tag = parser.findAll('div', attrs=list_of_attributes)

for ls in tag:
    for s in range(0,len(ls.contents)):
        try:
            if 'Session' in ls.contents[s].attrs['href']:
                mn.append('https://ash.confex.com/ash/2019/webprogram/'+ls.contents[s].attrs['href'])
        except:
            pass


# response = requests.post('https://ash.confex.com/ash/2019/webprogram/Session11552.html')
# soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
#
# list_of_attributes = {"class": "cricon"}  # A list of attributes that you want to check in a tag
# tag1 = soup.findAll('div', attrs=list_of_attributes)

dt=pd.DataFrame()
dt['Main Links']=mn
dt.to_excel('G:\Oct 18\ASH 18\Ash_Main_links2.xlsx')
```

I want my output 
Title- 201 Factors Associated with Response, CAR-T Cell In Vivo Expansion, and Progression-Free Survival after Repeat Infusions of CD19 CAR-T CellsClinically Relevant Abstract
Program: Oral and Poster Abstracts
Type: Oral
Session: 704. Immunotherapies I
Hematology Disease Topics & Pathways:
Biological, ALL, Leukemia, Diseases, Therapies, Lymphoma (any), CLL, CAR-Ts, Non-Hodgkin Lymphoma, DLBCL, Clinically relevant, Lymphoid Malignancies
Saturday, December 7, 2019: 12:30 PM
Valencia A (W415A), Level 4 (Orange County Convention Center)
Evandro D. Bezerra, MD1, Jordan Gauthier, MD, MSc1,2, Alexandre V. Hirayama, MD2, Barbara S. Pender, MSc2*, Reed M. Hawkins, BS2*, Aesha Vakil, MSc2*, Rachel N. Steinmetz, BS2*, Aude G. Chapuis, MD1,2*, Brian G. Till, MD1,2, Hans-Peter Kiem, MD, PhD1,3, Mazyar Shadman, MD, MPH1,2*, Ryan D. Cassaday, MD1,2, Stanley R. Riddell, MD1,2*, David G. Maloney, MD PhD1,3 and Cameron J. Turtle, MBBS, PhD1,2

1Department of Medicine, University of Washington, Seattle, WA
2Clinical Research Division, Fred Hutchinson Cancer Research Center, Seattle, WA
3Fred Hutchinson Cancer Research Center, Seattle, WA

Background
CD19-targeted chimeric antigen receptor-engineered (CD19 CAR)-T cell immunotherapy has shown promising efficacy in patients with relapsed or refractory (R/R) B-cell malignancies. The potential benefits of repeat infusions of CD19 CAR-T cells are unknown, and the factors associated with response, CAR-T cell in vivo expansion, and progression-free survival (PFS) after repeat infusion of CD19 CAR-T cells have not been investigated.

Methods

We analyzed the outcomes of patients with R/R B-cell malignancies after a second infusion of CD19 CAR-T cells (CART2) on a phase 1/2 trial (NCT01865617) at our institution. Responses after CAR-T cell therapy were evaluated around day 28 after infusion and defined according to the 2018 NCCN guidelines for acute lymphoblastic leukemia (ALL), 2018 iwCLL for chronic lymphocytic leukemia (CLL), and the Lugano criteria for non-Hodgkin lymphoma (NHL). Logistic, Cox and linear regression were used for multivariable analyses of response, progression-free survival and peak CD8+ CAR-T in blood, respectively. Bayesian model averaging was performed for variable selection.

Results

Forty-four patients evaluable for response (ALL, n=14; CLL, n=11; NHL, n=19) were included in this study. The median age at the time of CART2 was 58 (range, 23-73). Patients were heavily pre-treated (median prior therapies, 6; range, 2-13), and 16 patients (36%) had bulky (≥ 5cm) nodal or extramedullary disease. The median time from the first CAR-T infusion (CART1) to CART2 was 70 days (range, 28-712). Twenty-eight patients (64%) had received a CART1 dose ≥ 2x106 CAR-T cells/kg. Fifteen patients (32%) had not responded to CART1, 22 (50%) relapsed or progressed after having initially responded (complete response [CR], n=15; partial response [PR], n=7) to CART1; 7 (16%) received CART2 in PR after CART1. All characteristics are shown in the Table.

We observed responses in all disease types, including 3 of 14 ALL patients (21%; all CR/CRi), 4 of 11 CLL patients (36%; CR/CRi, n=3; partial response [PR], n=1), and 9 of 19 NHL patients (47%; CR, n=2; PR, n=7). After a median follow-up of 43 months (range, 16-66) in alive and responding patients, the estimated 4-year PFS probability in responders was 23% (95% CI, 9-59%). The 4-year overall survival probability in responders was 36% (95% CI 19-71%) compared to 24% (95% CI, 12-47) in non-responders.

Multivariable logistic regression modeling identified predictors of response after CART2: CART1 lymphodepletion (high-intensity cyclophosphamide and fludarabine [CyFlu] vs no CyFlu, OR=12.19, 95% CI, 1.10-1689.85, p=0.04), and peak of in vivo CAR-T cell expansion after CART2 (OR=2.31 per log10 CD8+ CAR-T cell/µL increase, 95% CI, 1.17-5.29, p=0.01).

In a multivariable Cox model, a higher peak of CD8+ CAR-T cells after CART2 (HR=0.47 per log10 CD8+ CAR-T cell/µL increase, 95%CI, 0.33-0.68, p<0.001); CART2 > CART1 cell dose was associated with longer PFS (HR=0.36, 95% CI, 0.16-0.86, p=0.02). This suggested that CD8+ CAR-T cell peak after CART2 and factors increasing CART2 peak (e.g. prevention of immune rejection or increase in the infused cell dose) are key elements associated with outcomes of CART2. Hence, we looked at factors associated with higher CD8+ CART2 peak. In multivariable linear regression, CART1 CyFlu predicted a higher peak of CD8+ CAR-T cells after CART2 (high-intensity CyFlu vs no CyFlu, p<0.001 ; low-intensity CyFlu versus no CyFlu, p=0.002) after adjusting for disease type (CLL vs ALL, p=0.02; NHL vs ALL, p=0.04) and the total CD19+ cell count in blood (p=0.02).

CyFlu being the most commonly used lymphodepletion prior to CAR-T cell therapy, we evaluated the impact of CART1 CyFlu lymphodepletion intensity by comparing high-intensity to low-intensity CyFlu in our multivariable models. Logistic regression suggested higher probabilities of response to CART2 in patients who received high-intensity compared to low-intensity CyFlu prior to CART1 (OR=3.83, 95%CI, 0.85-21.83, p=0.08). In multivariable analysis, CART1 high-intensity CyFlu was associated with higher CD8+ CAR-T cell numbers at day 60 after CART2 compared to low-intensity CyFlu (p=0.01) after adjusting for disease type and total CD19+ cell count in the blood.

Conclusion

Our findings suggest outcomes after second infusions of CD19 CAR-T cells might be improved with high-intensity CyFlu lymphodepletion prior to CART1 and by increasing the CAR-T cell dose at the time of CART2.

Comment: TL;DR ...............

Comment: the worst thing is `except: pass`. You may get error message and you will not know it. Better always use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` to see your errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky as the format of the data is different for each link, but essentially, you can get the html by passing the parameters in the `requests`, get the links, then go to each link and pull the data. There might be a more elegant way to do it, but this should get you going. I didn't go through the whole list as it takes a while, but got a decent chunk and printed first 5 rows as proof of concept:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math
import pandas as pd




url = 'https://ash.confex.com/ash/2019/htsearch.cgi'

df = pd.DataFrame()

for keyword in ['Adoptive cell therapy', 'Allogeneic', 'Autologous', 'Artificial T-Cell Receptors', 'BCMA', 'TACI', 'CD123']:

    payload = {
    'words': '%s' %keyword,
    'method': 'and',
    'pge': '1',
    'submit': 'Search',
    'byDayany': '1',
    'bySymposiumany': '1',
    'byAudienceany': '1',
    'action': 'search',
    'source': 'webprogram',
    'webprogrammode': 'default',
    'excludecontenttype': '1'}


    response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    tot_pages = math.ceil(int(soup.find('b').text)/10)

    for page in range(1,tot_pages+1):
        payload = {
        'words': '%s' %keyword,
        'method': 'and',
        'pge': '%s' %page,
        'submit': 'Search',
        'byDayany': '1',
        'bySymposiumany': '1',
        'byAudienceany': '1',
        'action': 'search',
        'source': 'webprogram',
        'webprogrammode': 'default',
        'excludecontenttype': '1'}

        response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        resultList = soup.find_all('li')
        for each in resultList:
            href = each.find('a')['href']

            link_url = 'https://ash.confex.com/ash/2019/webprogram/' + href
            response_alpha = requests.get(link_url)
            soup_alpha = BeautifulSoup(response_alpha.text, 'html.parser')

            headers = soup_alpha.find_all('span', {'class':'header'})

            header_col = []
            header_val = []
            for head in headers:
                a = head.text

                if head.next_sibling.name == 'br':
                    b = head.next_sibling.next_sibling
                else:    
                    b = head.next_sibling.strip()
                header_col.append(a)
                header_val.append(b)

            title = ' '.join(soup_alpha.find('h2').text.strip().split())

            print (title)

            time = soup_alpha.find('div', {'class':'datetime header'}).text.strip()
            loc = ' '.join(soup_alpha.find('div', {'class':'location'}).text.strip().split())

            try:
                authors = soup_alpha.find('div', {'class':'paperauthors'}).text.strip()
            except:
                authors = 'N/A'

            try:
                abstract = soup_alpha.find('div', {'class':'abstract'}).text.strip()
            except:
                abstract = 'N/A'

            try:
                disclosure = soup_alpha.find('div', {'class':'disclosure'}).text.strip()
            except:
                disclosure = 'N/A'

            data = header_val + [title, time, loc, authors, abstract, disclosure]
            col = header_col + ['title','time','location','authors','abstract','disclosure']

            temp_df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=col)



            df = df.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.head(5).to_string())
               Hematology Disease Topics & Pathways:                   Program:                                           Session: Type:                                           abstract                                            authors                                         disclosure                                           location                                         time                                              title
0  Biological, Therapies, CAR-Ts, Technology and ...  Oral and Poster Abstracts  703. Adoptive Immunotherapy: Mechanisms and Ne...   NaN  Success of adoptive T cell therapy (ATT) is de...  Stefanie Herda, PhD1*, Andreas Heimann, MSc1,2...  Disclosures: Bullinger: Bayer: Other: Financin...  Hall B, Level 2 (Orange County Convention Center)  Saturday, December 7, 2019, 5:30 PM-7:30 PM  1943 Long-Term T Cell Expansion Results in Inc...
1  Therapies, Technology and Procedures, cell exp...  Oral and Poster Abstracts  703. Adoptive Immunotherapy: Mechanisms and Ne...   NaN  The treatment of haematological malignancies w...  André Simoes, PhD*, Joanna Kawalkowska, PhD*, ...  Disclosures: Simoes: GammaDelta Therapeutics L...  Hall B, Level 2 (Orange County Convention Center)    Sunday, December 8, 2019, 6:00 PM-8:00 PM  3221 Vδ1+ T Cells: Adoptive Cell Therapy for t...
2  Diseases, Leukemia, antibodies, Biological, AM...  Oral and Poster Abstracts                     704. Immunotherapies: Poster I   NaN                                       Introduction  Rajneesh Nath, MD1, Eileen M Geoghegan2*, Matt...  Disclosures: Nath: Astellas: Consultancy; Daii...  Hall B, Level 2 (Orange County Convention Center)  Saturday, December 7, 2019, 5:30 PM-7:30 PM  1958 Sierra Clinical Trial Dosimetry Results S...
3  Diseases, Biological, Therapies, Hodgkin Lymph...  Oral and Poster Abstracts                    704. Immunotherapies: Poster II   NaN  BACKROUND: Hodgkin Lymphoma (HL) is characteri...  Fabio Guolo, MD1*, Paola Minetto, MD1, Filippo...  Disclosures: No relevant conflicts of interest...  Hall B, Level 2 (Orange County Convention Center)    Sunday, December 8, 2019, 6:00 PM-8:00 PM  3231 Adoptive Cell Therapy and Immune Check Po...
4  Diseases, Leukemia, ALL, Biological, AML, Ther...  Oral and Poster Abstracts  703. Adoptive Immunotherapy: Mechanisms and Ne...   NaN                                         Background  Hongbing Ma, MD, PhD1*, Ke Zeng, MD, PhD2*, Mi...  Disclosures: Iyer: Genentech/Roche: Research F...  Hall B, Level 2 (Orange County Convention Center)  Saturday, December 7, 2019, 5:30 PM-7:30 PM  1940 Adoptive Therapy with Cord Blood Regulato...
```